# PHP - Preg_match_all optional match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm having problems matching the[*] which is sometimes there and sometimes not. Anyone have suggestions?

```
$name = 'hello $this->row[today1][] dfh fgh df $this->row[test1] ,how good $this->row[test2][] is $this->row[today2][*] is monday'; 
echo $name."\n"; 
preg_match_all( '/\$this->row[.*?][*]/', $name, $match ); 
var_dump( $match );
```

output:
hello $this->row[test] ,how good $this->row[test2] is $this->row[today][*] is monday

```
array (
 0 => 
  array (
   0 => '$this->row[today1][*]',
   1 => '$this->row[test1] ,how good $this->row[test2][*]',
   2 => '$this->row[today2][*]',
  ),
)
```

Now the [0][1] match takes on too much because it is matching until the next '[]' instead of ending at '$this->row[test]' . I'm guessing the [*]/ adds a wildcard. Somehow need to check if the next character is [ before matching to []. Anyone?

Thanks

Comment: try `/(\$this->row\(\[^\)]*\))/`

Comment: try this,preg_match_all( '/\$this->row(\[.*?\])(\[\*\])?/', $name, $match );

Comment: both these don't match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[`, `]` and `*` are special meta characters in regex and you need to escape them. Also you need to make last `[]` optional as per your question.

Following these suggestions following should work:

```
$name = 'hello $this->row[today1][] dfh fgh df $this->row[test1] ,how good $this->row[test2][] is $this->row[today2][*] is monday'; 
echo $name."\n"; 
preg_match_all( '/\$this->row\[.*?\](?:\[.*?\])?/', $name, $match ); 
var_dump( $match );
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(20) "$this->row[today1][]"
    [1]=>
    string(17) "$this->row[test1]"
    [2]=>
    string(19) "$this->row[test2][]"
    [3]=>
    string(21) "$this->row[today2][*]"
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect thanks.  I was messing with that for a while.  The last ? make the previous segment optional?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes that's correct `?` makes previous group optional.